# Web SQL INSERT Callback not working properly

Tags: angularjs, web-sql

What I tried to do is to use an Angular service from within a controller to insert new data in a web-sql database and return a promise to update a displayed table with the new data.

```
.factory('DataProvider', function($q) {

var defer = $q.defer();
var db = openDatabase('testdb', '1.0', '', 5*1024*1024);

return {
    insert: function (data) {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  ' + 'test(nr integer primary key autoincrement, name)');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test (nr, name) VALUES (?, ?)', [data.id, data.name]);
        }, function () {
            defer.resolve(results);
        });
        return defer.promise;
    }
}
```

});

But when I now call:

```
Data.insert($scope.data).then(function() {
    //update data here
})
```

And try to fetch data the inserted entry won't be included.

Did I miss something or is it just that the callback on an INSERT is not executed after the INSERT was successfully completed?

Comment: You can't insert three values into two columns...

Comment: Sry, I overlooked that when I simplyfied the statement for the post

Comment: Your question is unclear - does the promise actually resolve but you can't see the inserted data, or does it not resolve at all? Add an error callback to `executeSql` and reject the promise in there, along with the error message, so you can see if it fails. (Alternatively, put the resolve/reject inside *the transaction*'s success/failure callbacks instead of *the statement*'s.)

Comment: Sry, the promise resolves but the inserted data is not (yet?) in the database if I try to SELECT it in the resolve.
Putting the promise on the transaction didn't work either.

Comment: where are you defining your `defer` variable in the function ?  can you include this section of your code ?

Comment: I edited the example to provide the factory with the definition of the `defer`